# cannot get html special chars from url

Tags: php

I'm very new to php and can't find answer to my issue.

I try to echo a string with special characters (ie. `&agrave;`,`&eacute;`) from the URL.

URL string:
`preview.php?content=<p>bl&agrave; &eacute; bla</p>`

Expected echoed result: `blà é bla`

So I do this:

```
$cont = $_GET['content'];
echo $cont;
```

Result:
    `bl`

So, even if my page has a `<meta charset="UTF-8">`, I tried:

```
$cont = $_GET['content'];
$cont = html_entity_decode($cont, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
echo $cont;
```

Same result:
    `bl`

I tried with a header (`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`) at top of the page with same result.

What's weird is that is I try this:

```
echo html_entity_decode("<p>bl&agrave; &eacute; bla</p>");
```

or even this:

```
echo "<p>bl&agrave; &eacute; bla</p>";
```

I get the expected result:
    `blà é bla`

So, I don't think it's a charset issue but can't understand why it works with the literal string but not with the get variable, can someone help me?

Comment: You need to encode the string before it goes onto the URL, to be able to decode it when you take it off. Ampersands are special characters in URLs and used to separate query string parameters.

Comment: `&` is a URL seperator for the next get parameter, you have to encode the url before using it. So `&` becomes `%26` after encoding. To get what i mean do after `echo $cont;` this `var_dump($_GET);` und you will see `Array ( [content] =>bl [agrave;_] => [eacute;_bla] => )` so `agrave;_` becomes an array key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode your URL with: [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) for example:

```
$url = 'content=' . urlencode('content=<p>bl&agrave; &eacute; bla</p>');
echo '<a href="preview.php?' . htmlentities($url) . '">';
```

Answer (score 1):

@JustOnUnderMillions, is correct.

E.g:

If you try to access data from URL like

```
http://localhost/index.php?content=%3Cp%3Ebl&agrave;%20&eacute;%20bla%3C/p%3E

echo $_GET['content'];

OUTPUT: bl
```

But when you pass data by encoding data like

```
http://localhost/index.php?content=%3Cp%3Ebl%26agrave%3B%20%26eacute%3B%20bla%3C%2Fp%3E

echo $_GET['content'];

OUTPUT: blà é bla
```

It is better to use [urlecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function for encode data in URL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

This works perfectly !

Actualy, as my URL is generated with javascript, I did a `encodeURIComponent` on my link's href variable and it works as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a URL with parameters as a value in a URL and through a javascript function, such as.

Pass the URL value through the PHP `urlencode()` function twice, like this

```
<?php

   $url = "index.php?id=4&pg=2";
   $url = urlencode(urlencode($url));
   echo "<a href=\"javascript:openWin('page.php?url=$url');\">";
?>
```

On the page being opened by the javascript function (page.php), you only need to `urldecode()` once, because when javascript 'touches' the URL that passes through it, it decodes the URL once itself. So, just decode it once more in your PHP script to fully undo the double-encoding.

```
<?php
   $url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
?>
```

If you don't do this, you'll find that the result URL value in the target script is missing all the var=values following `?` question mark.

```
index.php?id=4
```

kindly check this online tool also : [URL Encode](http://onlinew3tools.com/url-encode) , [URL Decode](http://onlinew3tools.com/url-decode)